# Why is the integral of the second chern class an integer?

Tags: chern-classes, vector-bundles, connections

I'm currently reading the paper ["Holonomy, the Quantum Adiabatic Theorem, and Berry's Phase"](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1983PhRvL..51.2167S) by Barry Simon.

Imagine a vector bundle with a connection $\nabla$. For simplicity, we assume that this is a $U(1)$ vector bundle. Parallel transport gives rise to the holonomy group, which assigns to each curve $C$ a number $e^{i\gamma(C)}$ that indicates how a vector is "rotated" when transporting it along the curve. In turns out that the phase change $\gamma(C)$ can be expressed as an integral of the curvature form over any surface $S$ that delimits the curve, $C = \partial S$,

$$ \gamma(C) = \int_{S} F^{\nabla} .$$

I am interested in the integral of the curvature form over the whole manifold, which turns out to be an integer multiple of $2\pi$,

$$ \int_{M} F^{\nabla} = 2\pi k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Simon notes that this "standard fact" is a consistency condition on the holonomy group. I can understand that: integrating over the whole manifold is like taking the holonomy of the constant path, which must be the identity.

What I would like to understand is the generalization to higher Chern classes. For instance,

> Why is the integral of the second Chern form an integer multiple of $4\pi^2$?

$$ \int_{M} F^{\nabla}\wedge F^{\nabla} = 4\pi^2 k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

I have a pedestrian proof for special cases, but I would like to understand a general reason behind this phenomenon. Is there a "higher holonomy" at work here?

Obviously, my knowledge of vector bundles and characteristic classes is rather limited. I can find my way around the book ["From Calculus to Cohomology"](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1983PhRvL..51.2167S), but have by no means absorbed all the material. Basically, my question is why the Chern classes defined via connections are normalized with a factor of $1/(2\pi)^k$.

Comment: A standard trick in the trade is the splitting principle, which
says in effect that you can pretend that your vector bundle (with
connection) is a sum of line bundles. There ways to justify it.
Apply it, then you'll see that the factors
of $2\pi (i)$ in the higher classes will have to multiply.

Comment: The question is already restricted to complex line bundles. Or are you saying that there is a way to interpret the second form $F^{\nabla}\wedge F^{\nabla}$ as a form of lower degree in a higher-dimensional bundle?

Comment: Greg, you can't mean this! $c_2$ and higher for a line bundle
are zero in cohomology. In fact, your integrand is zero. You want
to have at least rank $2$, and take $\int p(F\wedge F)$
where $p$ is an elementary symmetric function.

Comment: I mean that $p$ is a symmetric function of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Donu, just to be sure: you are saying that the differential 4-form $F\wedge F = (\sum_{ij} F_{ij}dx^i\wedge dx^j) \wedge F$ coming from a connection of a complex line bundle on, say, a four-dimensional torus must be exact? I did not know that. Could you give a quick pointer as to why?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood what you meant by "second Chern form". I realize your expression $\int F\wedge F$ is what I would
write as $c_1^2$, and  this certainly doesn't have to be zero.
Integrality is also easier to see in this case. See below.


Comment: The title of the question misrepresents the content.  Its not about the second Chern class.  In fact the question seems to be about the Chern-Weil formula for characteristic classes of a complex vector bundle.  Here is a more succinct statement.  Let $t$ be a formal variable, and consider  $$det(\frac{it\Omega}{2\pi}+Id)$$ where $\Omega$ is the curvature form of a connection on a complex vector bundle over a smooth manifold.  Why do  the coefficients of $t$ lie in the image of the integral cohomology of the manifold inside the DeRham cohomology?

Comment: Donu's remark at the beginning answers the question modulo checking that the integral over $i\Omega/2\pi$ over $\mathbb{C}P(1)$ for the standard connection on the canonical line bundle over $\mathbb{C}P(n)$
is $ 1$.  

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Greg,

I realize that I may as well write an answer rather than a  series of comments.
Although Jessica has given a good answer, I'll try to say this as concretely as possible,
since I now think I understand the question more clearly. The question was actually 
about the integrality of 
$$\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_M F\wedge F$$
where $F$ is the curvature of line bundle $V$ on a $4$-manifold $M$. This is what mathematicians
(I'm assuming you're a physicist) would call $c_1(V)^2$. 
The first thing is observe that
$c_1(V)\in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$, and that it's image in de Rham cohomology is
 given by $1/(2\pi i)[F]$. To see this in explicit terms, note that the classifying space
for line bundles in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^\infty$. This implies that the $V$ is the pull
back of the tautological bundle under a $C^\infty$ map  $f:M\to \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^N$,
for $N\gg 0$.  Working on projective space, we can check integrality of the class
$1/(2\pi i)[F]$ by  doing a direct calculation to see that this integrates to $1$ over a complex line (aka $2$-sphere). This suffices because the line generates $H_2(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^N)$. After this,  $c_1(V)^2=-1/4\pi^2[F]^2$ is automatically integral. That's it.

**Postscript:** If you are unhappy with the last part, you can replace $f$ with its composition with a generic projection to obtain $f:M\to \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$. Then your integral
becomes the degree of $f$ which is certainly an integer. Hopefully, you can take it from
here.

Comment: D'oh! I mixed up the nomenclature. $F \wedge F$ would be the second Chern *character* class according to "From Calculus to Cohomology". I'm not familiar with classifying spaces (why is there a map $f : M \to \mathbb{CP}^N$ for any manifold $M$), but I don't care much about that.

Comment: What seems more interesting is the integrality property. Assuming I only know de-Rham cohomology, could you elaborate on how I can detect whether a differential form from $H^k(M,\mathbb{C})$ is already a member of $H^k(M,\mathbb{Z})$? Is there a short reason why the wedge (cup) product of two integral forms is again integral?

Comment: If you only know deRham cohomology, then you don't know what $H^k(X, \mathbb{Z})$ means! OK, that's a bit unfair. It looks like in practice, you are interested in the subspace of $\omega$ in $H^k(X, \mathbb{R})$ such that, for every $k$-cycle $\sigma$, we have $\int_{\sigma} \omega \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is the image of $H^k(X, \mathbb{Z})$ in $H^k(X, \mathbb{R})$. So it sounds like what you want to know is why wedge product preserves this property of differential forms.

Comment: I'd be curious to see a direct proof of this, which doesn't go through the construction of $H^k(X, \mathbb{Z})$. Why don't you ask this as a separate question over on math.stackexchange.com ? (It will get closed here, because people here will have no problem assuming that integral cohomology exists.)

Comment: Thank you, David, I [have done as you suggested](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29797/434).

Answer (score 17):

Let $V$ be a complex vector bundle on a manifold $M$.  Chern classes can be defined by topological means (see Milnor's book on characteristic classes), which yields elements $c_k(V) \in H^{2k}(M;\mathbb{Z})$.  The normalization in the Chern-Weil theory is chosen so that the associated elements of de Rham cohomology groups $H^{2k}(M;\mathbb{R})$ agree with the integral elements, and thus integrate to give integers.

Comment: That is certainly true, but kind of dodges the question. One would have to show why the two agree up to a constant factor and then one would have to determine the constant factor to be precisely $(2\pi)^k$, and not, say $3\pi^{k/2}$. Both are currently beyond my understanding.

Comment: Let's say that you knew everything (functoriality, Whitney sum...) but the correct normalization. Then you'd have to calculate essentially one example: the universal bundle on a Grassmanian to get the correct constant. To do carry this out,
pull it up to the flag manifold (you won't lose anything,
since cohomology injects), split it has a sum of line bundles, and apply Whitney sum. That's what I meant in my previous comment.

Comment: Or, as the poser of the question is familiar with "From Calculus to Cohomology" you can quote Theroem 18.4 on page 184.


Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Appendix C in Milnor's book on characteristic classes. Essentially what is going on is that if you have a complex line bundle $L$ with connection $\nabla$ and curvature form $K_\nabla$, then the cohomology class of $\sigma_r(K_\nabla)$ is equal to $(2\pi i)^r c_r(L)$. Here $\sigma_r$ is the $r$th elementary symmetric function on the eigenvalues of the (matrix of the) connection.

The equality $\sigma_1(K_\nabla) = 2\pi i c_1(L)$ is rather transparent in case $L$ is a line bundle over a surface $S$ (as in the OP). Indeed, $\sigma_1 = \text{trace}$, and so what's being said is that $K_\nabla = 2\pi i c_1(L)$. And why is this true? Well, $K_\nabla$ is a closed $2$-form on $S$ that represents a characteristic cohomology class in $H^2(S;\mathbb{C})$, and therefore must be some multiple $a c_1(L)$ of the first Chern class. This constant $a$ is independent of $L$. So to compute it, all you need to do is work out some specific example. The formula
$$ \int_S F^\nabla = 2\pi i k $$
given in the OP (i.e. the Gauss--Bonnet formula!) does just that. It follows that $a=2\pi i$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to appendix C in Milnor's book!